# update field with another field another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a field in table1  with another field in  table2.I wrote the following query but it is not working.

```
UPDATE tempdata A
  SET A.new_user_id =
  (SELECT B.id FROM user B
  WHERE A.usr_email = B.usr_email)
```

It is giving "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" error. Anybody please help me.

Comment: This is because you have more users with the same email... then you should decide which id to take ?..

Comment: if you want to update all fields based on the value of the other table, use join instead. see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tempdata A, user B
  SET A.new_user_id = B.id
  WHERE A.usr_email = B.usr_email
```

Comment: this is an old syntax of join

Answer (score 1):

you can still join tables even if it is an update statement.

```
UPDATE tempdata A
       INNER JOIN user B
          ON A.usr_email = B.usr_email
SET A.new_user_id = B.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware that error means that in table user there are more than 1 rows with field usr_email equals to tempdata's one. Check for dupes before runniing the actual update statement with the LIMIT 1 a suggested by Salil

Answer (score 1):

This is also one way to handle this scenerio

```
UPDATE  A  
SET A.new_user_id = B.id
FROM tempdata A 
INNER JOIN user B ON A.usr_email = B.usr_email
```